# HTML-CSS, responsive grid layout

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, grid, resize

I'm playing around with w3.css stylesheet and I'm trying to make a 2x3 grid that adapts to fill the page. Every cell will then contain one image, which should adapt to the cell width or height (depending if the image is a portrait or a landscape).

I'd like to have my website always on the same page (desktop mode) with no scrollbars, so footer must be always visible too, grid must fill the page and images must resize to fit and center their own cell in the grid.

Is it possible to do this only using html and CSS, without JS? I feel like it is but I can't figure out how.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>My Website</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway">
<style>
body,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5 {font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif}
.w3-third img {
    opacity: 1; 
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 100%;
}
.w3-third img:hover {opacity: 0.8}
</style>    
<body class="w3-light-grey w3-content" style="max-width:1920px">

<!-- Sidebar/menu -->
<nav class="w3-sidebar w3-bar-block w3-grey w3-animate-left w3-text-black w3-collapse w3-top w3-center" style="z-index:3;width:300px;font-weight:bold" id="mySidebar"><br>
  <h3 class="w3-padding-64 w3-center"><b>NOME<br>COGNOME</b></h3>
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="w3_close()" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-padding w3-hide-large">CLOSE</a>
  <br><a href="#immagini" onclick="w3_close()" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Immagini</a> 
  <a href="#musica" onclick="w3_close()" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Musica</a> 
  <a href="#interessi" onclick="w3_close()" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Interessi</a>
</nav>

<!-- Top menu on small screens -->
<header class="w3-container w3-top w3-hide-large w3-white w3-xlarge w3-padding-16">
  <span class="w3-left w3-padding">SOME NAME</span>
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="w3-right w3-button w3-white" onclick="w3_open()">?</a>
</header>

<!-- Overlay effect when opening sidebar on small screens -->
<div class="w3-overlay w3-hide-large w3-animate-opacity" onclick="w3_close()" style="cursor:pointer" title="close side menu" id="myOverlay"></div>

<!-- !PAGE CONTENT! -->
<div class="w3-main" style="margin-left:300px">

  <!-- Push down content on small screens --> 
  <div class="w3-hide-large" style="margin-top:83px"></div>
  
  <!-- Grid -->
  <div class="w3-white" style="min-height:920px">
      
  <div class="w3-row-padding" style="min-height:50%; padding-top:16px">
    <div class="w3-third">
      <img class="w3-round-large" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/AWhCM.jpg" onclick="onClick(this)" alt="Penguins">
    </div>
    <div class="w3-third">
      <img class="w3-round-large" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/AWhCM.jpg" onclick="onClick(this)" alt="Penguins">
    </div>
    <div class="w3-third">
      <img class="w3-round-large" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/A4tmi.jpg" onclick="onClick(this)" alt="Penguins">
    </div>
  </div>
      
  <div class="w3-row-padding" style="min-height:50%; height:50%; padding-top:16px; padding-bottom:16px">
    <div class="w3-third">
      <img class="w3-round-large" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/A4tmi.jpg" onclick="onClick(this)" alt="Penguins">
    </div>
    <div class="w3-third">
      <img class="w3-round-large" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/AWhCM.jpg" onclick="onClick(this)" alt="Penguins">
    </div>
    <div class="w3-third">
      <img class="w3-round-large" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/AWhCM.jpg" onclick="onClick(this)" alt="Penguins">
    </div>
  </div>
   
  </div>

  <!-- Modal for full size images on click-->
  <div id="modal01" class="w3-modal w3-black" style="padding-top:0" onclick="this.style.display='none'">
    <span class="w3-button w3-black w3-xlarge w3-display-topright">X</span>
    <div class="w3-modal-content w3-animate-zoom w3-center w3-transparent w3-padding-64">
      <img id="img01" class="w3-image">
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Footer -->
  <footer class="w3-container w3-center w3-padding-16 w3-grey" >  
    This is a footer
  </footer>
  
<!-- End page content -->
</div>

<script>

// Script to open and close sidebar
function w3_open() {
    document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("myOverlay").style.display = "block";
} 
function w3_close() {
    document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("myOverlay").style.display = "none";
}

// Modal Image Gallery
function onClick(element) {
  document.getElementById("img01").src = element.src;
  document.getElementById("modal01").style.display = "block";
}

</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, check out flexbox: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ I didn't really get the issue, please make a UI where I can see the result you expect.

Comment: just resize the window, you'll see the footer is not visible anymore since I've set `min-height:920px` on the grid div which is good only for 1920x1080 resolution. I want the cells to resize. I'll check flexbox.